# Select count of different values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join

I have two tables, A and B, structured as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `code` VARCHAR(1),
  `type` VARCHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO TableA
  (`id`, `code`, `type`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'A', 'r'),
  ('2', 'A', 'o'),
  ('3', 'A', 'u'),
  ('4', 'B', 'h');

CREATE TABLE TableB (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `sid` INTEGER,
  `code` VARCHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO TableB
  (`id`, `sid`, `code`)
VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'A'),
  ('1', '1', 'A'),
  ('1', '1', 'A'),
  ('2', '1', 'B'),
  ('2', '1', 'B'),
  ('1', '2', 'A'),
  ('1', '2', 'A'),
  ('2', '2', 'A');
```

the output of this query should be like this

```
sid      r     o     u
1        3     2     0
2        2     1     0
```

table A has a foreign key from table B which is the id. what I want to get is how many times each sid accessed each type of table A.

Comment: The `code` column appearing in both tables would seem to be unnormalized data, and it seriously throws off anyone looking at your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Left join Table B to Table A and aggregate:

```
select b.sid,
  sum(a.type = 'r') r,
  sum(a.type = 'o') o,
  sum(a.type = 'u') u
from TableB b left join TableA a
on b.id = a.id
group by b.sid
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8wmA9RCjVfuK2CTWAVs16j/0).
Results:

```
| sid | r   | o   | u   |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1   | 3   | 2   | 0   |
| 2   | 2   | 1   | 0   |
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but what if I have more than 50 types in table A. is it useful to repeat the sum function for 50 times ?

Comment: MySql does not offer any pivot functionality, so in this case the only way is conditional aggregation for each type like the code in my answer.